# Is asking about an alternative to a cable TV off topic?

Tags: discussion, allowed-topics

I am just trying to find if anybody used a particular internet TV company. Not sure if it's off-topic. It's kind of about saving money by replacing expensive cable TV bill with a cheaper alternative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It's kind of about saving money by replacing expensive cable TV bill with a cheaper alternative.

This could be on-topic if generalized, but realize that many people's media consuption habits will be *highly* subjective, so be careful.

For example, I personally could care less about sports, but the idea that you could be without access to the latest cricket, football, soccer, or [jai-alai](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jai_alai) game broadcast would be unthinkable to some.

Comment: I'll add: Subject would fall under tag 'cost-cutting'.  See http://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cost-cutting